# Filtering before multivariate analysis

Tags: multivariate-analysis, feature-selection

I am a newbie in statistics and this may be a silly question.

For a n << p problem, I wonder if it is feasible to first filter variables according to some criterion, for example correlation between each independent variable and Y, and then use the left number of variables to build model and select variable according to the model?
Apologize that this may not be even a clear question. Let me give an example.

Suppose we have 100 samples and 1000 variables. One continuous dependent variable (Y). First, I exclude variable one by one that has no (linear or non-linear) relationship with Y. Then suppose after this filtering, I have 300 variable left. Then, use this 300 variable to build partial least square (PLS) model. Then use this PLS model to finally select important variables according to VIP score.

Another example is that I use these 1000 variable to build random forest. Then according to the VIP of this random forest to select top 50 important variables and finally build a new random forest model using these 50 variables and use this random forest as the final model to predict, etc.

I think there must be something wrong with these two examples, but I just don't know what it is.

Comment: What about regularized regression ? Lasso, ridge etc.  They can be found in the R package glmnet.  These methods were originally developed to deal with the $ p>n$ issue.

Comment: Thanks aginensky. I am not concerning about what methods we can use for p>>n problem. I just want to know what would be wrong if I manually delete some variable that I think is not relevant to Y and use the rest of variables to do regression.

Comment: @ Frank- imho the question you ask is actually very subtle and hard.  Even well reasoned and well intentioned removal of variables can be problematical.  See this http://journals.plos.org/plosmedicine/article?id=10.1371/journal.pmed.0020124  for example.  However, either CV, bootstrapping,  or better yet, train and test can  provide a practical justification.  So use 70 of the samples to create your model with 50 variables.  What's the prediction rmse compared to the train rmse ?